# How to get boolean value of ,minimum 1 selected radio button from group ,by name(jquery)

Tags: jquery

How to get boolean value instead of actual selected text from group of radio button by attribute name using jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [checking at least one radio button is selected from each group (with jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028683/checking-at-least-one-radio-button-is-selected-from-each-group-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$("input[name='MainColumn']").is(':checked')

```js
console.log($("input[name='MainColumn']").is(':checked'));//true or false 
console.log($("input:radio[name=MainColumn]:checked").length);//0 or 1

$("input").on('click',function(){
console.log($("input[name='MainColumn']").is(':checked'));//true or false 
console.log($("input:radio[name=MainColumn]:checked").length)//0 or 1

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="MainColumn" value="male"> Male<br>
  <input type="radio" name="MainColumn" value="female"> Female<br>
  <input type="radio" name="MainColumn" value="other"> Other
```